# Properly installing nlp

Tags: python, module, nlp

My code:

```
import nlp
def tokenize_sentences(text):
    tokens = nlp(text)
    sentences = [sent.text for sent in nlp(text).sents]
    return sentences
text = "Some phrases that I use as a test. The context is not important. Test sentence.

sentences = tokenize_sentences(text)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ec796e2a8070> in <module>
----> 1 sentences = tokenize_sentences(text)

<ipython-input-2-aa259d17fc09> in tokenize_sentences(text)
      1 def tokenize_sentences(text):
----> 2     tokens = nlp(text)
      3     sentences = [sent.text for sent in nlp(text).sents]
      4     #print(sentences)
      5     #for sent in tokens.sents:

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried installing again `!pip install NLP-python`, `!pip install NLP`, `!pip install nlp`. Then when I tried the following, 'NLP' wasn't found.

```
from NLP import NLP
nlp = NLP()
```

I know the error is somewhere in the import, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the attributes in your code, it seems the library you are looking for is not `NLP-python` but `spacy`.

```
pip3 install spacy
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then in your code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the nlp object. you have not imported the spacy library